# Embed html pages as sections in a html with AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, user-interface

Three persons are working on different sections of a page.One may be working on  moving images,another must be working on tab section.So my question is

1) Is it possible to embed these all html as sections in a html page and then showing it in ui-view as a whole?

2)Will it affect performance of page?

3)If it affects then best way to combine multiple functionalities in one html page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the different sections can be Angular components: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component